# How can I get imgui up and running on linux and clion

Tags: clion

Disclaimer: I'm a jvm user, I know barely enough just to set a native program via cmake

I'd like to get the imgui [glfw-opengl3](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/example_glfw_opengl3) example running under Ubuntu (19.10)

In Windows is pretty easy, there is already a [vs project file](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_glfw_opengl3/example_glfw_opengl3.vcxproj)

But on Linux I have no idea how to continue.

Trying to use CLion, I followed [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-makefile-projects.html#):

- create a compilation db
- installed the Makefile plugin
- and opened the file in CLion

now, how/what shall I do to have a (debug) configuration?

Edit: there is now also a [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://gist.github.com/rokups/f771217b2d530d170db5cb1e08e9a8f4#gistcomment-3690497), for those who are interested

Comment: AFAIK you need to create Custom build [target](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/custom-build-targets.html) to be able run/debug

Comment: I don't have any of external tools? https://i.imgur.com/ZNfIZMc.png

Comment: You have to create `build` (`clean` is optional) tool by yourself. Just click on `+`.

Comment: Ok, [then](https://imgur.com/wen4HKB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from scratch.

After generating `compile_commands.json` with [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) for exmaple (Just run `bear make`) I've opened compile_commands.json as a project in CLion.

Then you need to create a custom build target. Click on Add Configuration in the toolbar and find `Custom Build Application`
[Add Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUwE0.png)

Then click on Configure Custom Build Targets link and add a new target (`example_glfw_opengl3` in my case). As for build I use external task with the next parameter:

- program: `make`
- arguments: `all`
- Working directory: `$ContentRoot$`

Pretty similar for clean:

- program: `make`
- arguments: `clean`
- Working directory: `$ContentRoot$`

Then you need to build executable via CLion menu `Build | Build Project`. Now you can specify the executable in the Custom build Application run configuration menu. That's it. Now you can Run/Debug your app.

Comment: One last question, is there a way to have the imgui source files in the project view as well? [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/DlM3osd.png)